# What is the default timed out time for Popen.communicate?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

In Python I am using subprocess to call a long running command and `proc.communicate()` so as to be able to log/print the output in realtime as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

However, I am getting a `fatal: Application timed out after 00:10:00.3431942` error message after about 10 minutes through the application run. Hence, I am here to check if `Popen.communicate` has a timeout and if yes, what is the default timeout that gets applied if it is not set manually?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a configurable timeout for Popen. Maybe it's the process you're calling that times out. Does the "fatal" error message form part of an Exception trace? If not then you can probably assume that it's the called application that is timing out

Comment: The called application is my own application wrapped inside MONAI Framework. But it doesnt show a traceback even after heavy use of try-except block. It doesnt enter into my except blocks. Secondly, if you lookup the Popen doc there is a timeout parameter which raise my suspicion. Doc here https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: OK - So if no exception is being caught in your Python code (which you've chosen not to share) then it must be your application that's timing out. Try running your application outside of Python. I would suggest that as the Popen documentation doesn't say anything about what happens if *timeout* is None then one should assume that it blocks indefinitely.